# I am getting the below error while generating .aab release file in react native expo

Tags: react-native, build, expo, android-app-bundle

after running this command I'm getting this error.

```
eas build --platform android
```

Please provide a solution I would appreciate that.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are receiving indicates that there was an issue with writing the bundle file due to a network error. This could be caused by a variety of factors, such as a slow or unstable network connection, or a firewall blocking the connection.

So, just recheck your connection and run the same command.

this worked for me.